# System.ListException: Duplicate id in list

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

I have a trigger that is a bulk update. Sometimes the same object will make it into my update list more than once, which causes the error:

> ERROR: autostd2: execution of AfterInsertcaused by:
>   System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:
>   0019000001CBLegAAHClass.SportsHelper.AccountCountUpdate: line 39,
>   column 1Trigger.autostd2: line 31, column 1

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

```
Public class SportsHelperToUpdateAccountCount{

    public static void AccountCountUpdate(list<Sports__c> SportsList){

        List<Account> AcRec = [select id,name from account];

        List<Account>Aclist = new list<Account>();
        List<Id> S1 = new list<Id>();
        Map<id,decimal> SpMap = new Map<id,decimal>();
        Decimal i =0;

        for(Sports__C sp: SportsList){
            system.debug('account id is '+sp.account__c);
            S1.add(sp.Account__c);
        }


        System.debug('I value is'+i);
        list<Sports__c> Splist =[select id,name,account__c from Sports__c  where account__c in:S1];
        i = [select count() from sports__c where account__c in: S1 and sports_fee__c>50];


        List<Account> Alist = [select id,name,count__c from account where id in:S1];


        for(sports__c sp1: sportslist){
            for(Account ac: Alist) {
                //if(sp1.account__c == ac.id){
                system.debug('I value is'+i);
                ac.count__c = i;
                system.debug('Count value is '+ac.count__c);
                Aclist.add(ac);
                //}
            }
        }
        update Aclist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Set` data structure.

Comment: @RohitMourya Never use `Set<SObject>` unless you are *really really* sure you know what you are doing. If you want unique by Id, use `Map<Id, SObject>`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, I got your point. It might identify unique on various fields and not just by `Id`. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may be trying to count the number of `Sports__c` objects that have a `sports_fee__c` value that is greater than 50 per `Account` object.

A query with no where clause like this:

```
[select id,name from account]
```

will eventually hit a governor limit (and will consume a lot of time/heap until it does) so is best avoided; use a `where`clause to limit to the relevant set of rows.

You also only have one count value:

```
Decimal i =0;
```

so if `Sports__c` objects from multiple `Account`s are involved the results will be wrong.

The simplest and best way to get a count correct is to use a [Rollup Summary](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&type=0) field, and in your case make use of the "Filter Criteria" to only count where `sports_fee__c > 50`. The objects need to be in a master-detail relationship for this to be possible. No triggers are needed at all: the numbers are just automatically correctly calculated.

Alternately, you can make use of [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) to do the counting in a single query greatly simplifying the code and so reducing the chances of the code being wrong. That code would look something like this (untested) code:

```
public class SportsHelperToUpdateAccountCount{

    public static void AccountCountUpdate(list<Sports__c> sports) {

        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Sports__c s : sports) accountIds.add(s.Account__c);

        // The "group by" guarantees one result per Account so no Map needed
        Account[] updates = new Account[] {};
        for (AggregateResults ar : [
                select Account__c a, count() c
                from Sports__c
                where Account__c in :accountIds
                group by Account__c
                ]) {
            updates.add(new Account(
                    Id = (Id) ar.get('a'),
                    Count__c = (Integer) ar.get('c')
                    ));
        }
        update updates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your collection type from `List` to `Set`.

```
List<Account> accList = [...];
```

**Lists:**

> A list is an ordered collection of elements that are
>   distinguished by their indices. List elements can be of any data
>   type—primitive types, collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and
>   built-in Apex types.

**Sets:**

> A set is an unordered collection of elements that do not contain any
>   duplicates. Set elements can be of any data type—primitive types,
>   collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types.

Comment: Generally best to not rely on applying `Set` to the SObject as two SObjects could have the same Id but different other field values and so still be distinct. Hence the common use of of e.g `Map<Id, Account>` where the collection is unique by `Id` yet holds the SObject value.